# Create a function to designate values as monthly or quarterly

Tags: python, pandas, function, date

I have a column with dates called "DATE" in the format MM/DD/YYYY. I want to create a new column "TIME" that iterates over each row in "DATE" and if the months are 01,04,07,10, assigns them the label of "quarterly" in the new column. Months 01,04,07 and 10 should have both a "quarterly" and "monthly" label.

Comment: `df['Time'] = np.where(df['Date'].dt.month.isin([1,4,7,10]), 'quarterly', 'monthly')` make sure your date column is datetime

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in function for this, you can do the following

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['quarter'] = df['date'].dt.to_period('Q')
```

You can use any of the [following values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-period-aliases) in addition to 'Q'. Such as

```
Alias    Description
B        business day frequency
D        calendar day frequency
W        weekly frequency
M        monthly frequency
Q        quarterly frequency
A, Y     yearly frequency
H        hourly frequency
T, min   minutely frequency
S        secondly frequency
L, ms    milliseconds
U, us    microseconds
N        nanoseconds
```

Turning this into a function can be something like

```
def date_to_period(df_src, date_col, period_alias):

    df = df_src.copy()    

    df[date_col] = pd.to_datetime(df[date_col])
    df['period'] = df[date_col].dt.to_period(period_alias)

    return df['period'].values

# Example
#  df['quarter'] = date_to_period(df, 'date','Q')
#  df['month'] = date_to_period(df, 'date','M')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function in Pandas to create a new column based on the values in the "DATE" column.

```py
def label_months(date):
    month = date.split('/')[0]
    label = 'monthly'
    if month in ['01', '04', '07', '10']:
        label = 'quarterly'
    return label

# Create a new column "TIME" based on the "DATE" column
df['TIME'] = df['DATE'].apply(label_months)
```

The function `label_months`  takes a date string as input, extracts the month, and returns either "monthly" or "quarterly" as a string. It returns "quarterly" if the month is one of ['01', '04', '07', '10']; otherwise, it returns "monthly". The apply function then uses this `label_months` function to create a new column "TIME" in the `DataFrame`.

Comment: @nick1 you mean they appear as an array, like this `[monthly, quarterly]`? They shouldn't  since the function `label_months()` returns a string. `join()` method returns a string created by joining the elements of the array.

Comment: @nick1 if I understand the issue correctly, you want the TIME column to show either "monthly" or "quarterly", and not both in the same cell. If that is what you want, you can update the `label_months()` to return only a label instead. Initialize a variable `label` with the value "monthly". If it is a quarterly month, change the value of `label` to "quarterly".  Return the value of `label`. Check edit.